# How to deploy wordpress with mongodb with docker?

Tags: wordpress, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a student who is interested in deploying WordPress with MongoDB using Docker, but I'm not sure how to install the necessary plugins in a docker-compose file. I read somewhere that WordPress wasn't designed to use NoSQL databases, but with the help of some plugins, it should work. Here's what I have so far:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mongo
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: example
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: db
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

volumes:
  wordpress:
  db:
```

The thing is even with the already defined environment variables, I see the following `config.php` file:

```
// ** Database settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', getenv_docker('WORDPRESS_DB_NAME', 'wordpress'));

/** Database username */
define('DB_USER', getenv_docker('WORDPRESS_DB_USER', 'example username'));

/** Database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', getenv_docker('WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD', 'example password'));
```

The config (dbuser, dbname, etc) have not changed according to my set environment variables.

Any help on how to properly deploy WordPress with MongoDB using Docker and the necessary plugins would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm thinking if you are mixing the things here. Since Mongo is a non-SQL database, I believe it's not straightforward to run WordPress only changing the database configs to connect it to a non-SQL database. As you mentioned, you read about some plugins to do it, btw doing that sounds weird to me. Why you would like to run it using Mongo? If you want to run the application using a sql database in docker compose I can help you

Comment: What's the core problem? Installing Wordpress? Using it with MongoDB? Using it with Docker?

Comment: The core problem is using it with MongoDB. And then how to configure it in the docker compose to do so. Or if needed creating a new image based on the WordPress one to install necessary plugins. It's just some sort of assignment by the prof.

Comment: If the problem is not related to Docker after all, please remove the irrelevant parts from your question by editing it. Try to get Wordpress running without a Docker setup first, to make this less complicated